# When accessing window from view model it is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

What i want to do is to create **property** into the model ***ComboBoxItemChange.cs*** of type **ILoginView** that is the **interface** which LoginWindow.xaml.cs is deriving. Using this property i want to grant access to the elements inside LoginWindow. I red that  this is correct way to do it using **MVVM** pattern.
My **problem** is that property is always *null*.


**LoginWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class LoginWindow : Window, ILoginView
{
    public LoginWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       this.DataContext = new ComboBoxItemChange();
       (this.DataContext as ComboBoxItemChange).LoginWindow = this as ILoginView;
    }

    public void ChangeInputFieldsByRole(string role)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(role);
    }
}
```

**ComboBoxItemChange.cs**

```
public class ComboBoxItemChange : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ILoginView LoginWindow { get; set; }

    private void ChangeloginWindowInputFields(string value)
    {
       if (LoginWindow == null)
            return;
       LoginWindow.ChangeInputFieldsByRole(value);
    }
}
```

**ILoginView.cs**

```
public interface ILoginView
{
    void  ChangeInputFieldsByRole(string role);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the instances are same for ComboBoxItemChange?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't calling constructor from somewhere else `new ComboBoxItemChange();` in your code?

Comment: Well, i searched this class name in whole solution, there were tree matches- 1) `public class ComboBoxItemChange : INotifyPropertyChanged`
2) `public ComboBoxItemChange()` that is constructor in that class
3) `<Grid.Resources><src:ComboBoxItemChange x:Key="myDataSource"/></Grid.Resources>` inside my LoginWindow.xaml.
Basically this class is used only by property change trigger, thats all.

Comment: What you are doing with the one declared in XAML. Most likely issue is that instance only. Can you post XAML code for it's usage?

Comment: The only place where this class is used in xaml is:
` <Grid.Resources><src:ComboBoxItemChange x:Key="myDataSource"/></Grid.Resources>`
then only that **myDataSource** is used.

Comment: So, that's an issue you set `DataContext` from code behind and set ILoginView for that instance. But in XAML, you create another instance and use that. Just remove the instance from XAML and use the one created in code behind.

Comment: Well, you are right, @RohitVats .. I removed `Source={StaticResource myDataSource}` and `<Grid.Resources><src:ComboBoxItemChange x:Key="myDataSource"/></Grid.Resources>`from my xaml code and it worked without my created static class! Thank you very much, learned things! :)

Comment: Great I have converted the comment to answer. Hope it helps you.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comment:

There are two different instances you are creating:

- One in code behind where you set `ILoginView` to window itself
- Second in Grid resources where you haven't set `ILoginView`.

**Remove the instance you declared in XAML** and let the bindings resolved from the instance you created in code behind. *(DataContext will automatically be inherited for child controls)*.